How to wait until all other parallel promises resolve?
I am currently implementing a client-side token refreshing script for a website, and reached a minor problem when the access token needed to be refreshed.
For some pages, the client fetched multiple (let's say two) documents from the server (which both needed to be fetched with authorised requests, that is with an access token), so when the client access token was expired, this simultaneous fetching invoked two token refresh operations, and the client saved the final access token of the refresh operation that concluded last. This is a waste of resources as the first access token was never used or even saved to the client.
In order to solve this, I made the process that refreshed tokens create a temporary localStorage entry:
async function getAccessToken(auth) {
  // Check if the current token is valid, and return it if so
  ...
  // Case when token needs to be refreshed
  localStorage.setItem("TOKEN_PENDING", "TOKEN_PENDING");
  // Refresh the token
  ...
  const res = await fetch(...);
  ...
  // Clean up after refresh
  localStorage.removeItem("TOKEN_PENDING");
  // Return the new token
  ...
}

Obviously, I now need to check if this entry has been created prior to refreshing the token:
const isTokenPending = () => localStorage.getItem("TOKEN_PENDING") != null;

async function getAccessToken(auth) {
  // Check if the current token is valid, and return it if so
  ...
  // Case when token needs to be refreshed
  localStorage.setItem("TOKEN_PENDING", "TOKEN_PENDING");

  // Check if the token is currently being refreshed in a parallel instance of the function
  if (isTokenPending()) {
    while (isTokenPending()) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    }
    console.info("Token finished refreshing");
    // Recursively call the function, which will now produce the new valid token
    return getAccessToken(auth);
  }

  localStorage.setItem("TOKEN_PENDING", "TOKEN_PENDING");
  // Refresh the token
  ...
  const res = await fetch(...);
  ...
  // Clean up after refresh
  localStorage.removeItem("TOKEN_PENDING");
  // Return the new token
}

The problematic part is when the function detects that the temporary entry is present, and waits until the token is refreshed in some other instance of the function. Currently, I've tried the approach seen in the while loop:
while (isTokenPending()) {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
}

However, I'm not sure this is a good enough solution since it looks hacky and isn't obvious at first glance what's going on. I used a self-resolving promise which resolves after a timeout of 0 milliseconds, which seems not to do anything. However, the fact that the promise is being awaited allows the program to "yield" the asynchronous processing and simultaneously handle the parallel instance which is refreshing the token, allowing the while loop to finally end.
I also tried removing the hackish 0-millisecond promise, but then the process consumed all processing time and didn't allow the parallel instance to refresh the token. This resulted in the website hanging/freezing.
I expected the two invocations of the function to run in parallel, and for the while loop to wait until the second one completed, which would make the next call to isTokenPending() return false.
Additionally, I found this SO post:
How to wait for a JavaScript Promise to resolve before resuming function?
However, the accepted answer states that there is no way to achieve this, and it is dated 9 years ago so if this even applies to my problem I'd like to know if anything has changed since then. Perhaps the use of yield?
So what I'm really asking is how could I allow this part of the code (with the while loop) to wait for allow the asynchronous code to finish completing, and then continue when there are no unresolved promises?
Thanks in advance for your proposed solutions.

Why did you use localstorage instead of a simple variable? Do you need the value to be shared across tabs?

It is more a matter of design than a matter of implementation. Maybe you want to forget about semaphores, promises and loops for a moment and do some rubber duck thinking about what the workflow is exactly? Then describe it here algorithmically and we can find a straightforward solution. Right now it is too complicated.

Also, two things to have in mind: 0ms means asap and not immediately and there is no parallelism -JavaScript engine never runs two pieces of code at the same time.

@dpant I'd follow up with your comments but I am satisfied with an answer provided below. I think it clears up the workflow quite well if my explanation wasn't adequate. Thanks

If you're only worried about issuing one token request per tab/window, this can be done very easily by storing the Promise that will return with a resolved access token. If you are trying to issue one token request per browser even among multiple tabs/windows, you could use the storage event to identify when some other browsing context (tab or window) makes that change.
Firstly: the question you linked, How to wait for a JavaScript Promise to resolve before resuming function?, effectively asks if you can pause a function that isn't async. That answer is "no", but that's not what you're trying to do here.
If all you care about is the current tab, then it becomes very easy: separate the logic that refreshes the access token from the logic that gets it.
/** Private. Always returns a fresh access token. */
async function refreshAccessToken(auth) {
  // Debug assert.
  if (isTokenPending()) throw new Error("Called during refresh.");

  localStorage.setItem("TOKEN_PENDING", "TOKEN_PENDING");
  const res = await fetch(...);
  localStorage.removeItem("TOKEN_PENDING");
  return res;
}

/** Private. Stores a promise for the current access token in flight. */
let accessTokenPromise = null;

/** Always returns a valid access token. Could be async if you'd like. */
function getAccessToken() {
  // If this is the first call, fetch. If the token is stale, fetch.
  // If the token is pending, do not refresh, the promise covers that case.
  if (!accessTokenPromise || accessTokenHasExpired()) {
    // Do not await this. You want to store the promise.
    accessTokenPromise = refreshAccessToken(getAuth());
  }
  // In an async function, you can optionally await this for better debug messages.
  return accessTokenPromise;
}

If you want to store this between tabs, then it's almost the same, but instead you'd want to detect the case where you have TOKEN_PENDING set but your browsing context isn't the one that initiated it (presumably by storing a local boolean). In that case, you could either poll through a repeated setTimeout or subscribe through a storage event that detects when the other tab has set the token.
/** Listens for a token update. Uses manual promises to convert event listener. */
function listenForTokenUpdate() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let listener = (e) => {
      if (e.key === "TOKEN") {
        window.removeEventListener(listener);
        resolve(e.newValue);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('storage', listener);
  });
}

/** Always returns a valid access token. Could be async if you'd like. */
function getAccessToken() {
  if (tokenIsPendingFromAnotherTab()) {
    // Another tab is fetching. Wait for it.
    accessTokenPromise = listenForTokenUpdate();
  } else if (!accessTokenPromise || accessTokenHasExpired()) {
    // We need to fetch the new access token ourselves.
    accessTokenPromise = refreshAccessToken(getAuth());
  }
  // Either the promise is still valid or has been recently updated above.
  return accessTokenPromise;
}

Note that you may need to adjust the above code depending on how exactly you store your token. Though Javascript is effectively single-threaded within a browsing context, if you are syncing data between multiple browsing contexts via local storage, you might see listenForTokenUpdate catch the TOKEN update before other tab has cleared the TOKEN_PENDING status, meaning that the right call order would have your other tab listen for storage event that would never arrive. Likewise you might need to catch the case where both browsing contexts detect that no other tab is fetching and then start fetching simultaneously, though ultimately the cost of that race condition is pretty low.

tab 1 --> set TOKEN_PENDING --> refreshAccessToken ------------------> clear TOKEN_PENDING 

tab 2 -----------> listenForTokenUpdate() -> resolve -> listen again ---------------- ...>


Wow, thank you for the elaborate response! It was very insightful. I think I could combine both cases you proposed, and address the problem of catching the TOKEN update before TOKEN_PENDING clears by simply cutting out the middleman and adjusting the listenForTokenUpdate function to wait for the update of TOKEN_UPDATE, instead, and resolving when the event is a key removal. This way the event listener could be used for both same-tab and cross-tab updates, which is just as well as I don't know how I could differentiate the two in tokenIsPendingInAnotherTab. Thanks again!

You're welcome! I do think you could set a boolean variable for tokenPendingInThisTab from within refreshAccessToken to differentiate the cases, which you might need to do anyway: the note at the top of the storage event MDN page notes that "This won't work on the same browsing context that is making the changes". You might need to keep the two cases separate, but that should still be tractable. Your idea of watching for TOKEN_PENDING removal sounds fine to me, too--that should help avoid the race condition.

I can see what you are going for, but I feel like it might be a little bit more complicated than it needs to be.
Assuming that all your requests use the same Token, you could check validity of the token before doing any of the document fetching requests.
This ensure that only one refresh request is done, and that all the document fetching request have a valid token. I was thinking something like
async validateToken() {
  if(!isTokenValid) {
    const refreshedToken = await refrehToken();
    storeUpdatedToken(refreshedToken)
    return refreshedToken;
  }

  return getStoredValidToken();
}

async function fetchDocuments(documentToFetch) {
  const validToken = await validateToken()

  for(let i = 0; i < documentToFetch; i ++) {
    await fetchDocument(validToken);
  }
}

Now, this code will run all the fetchDocument request one after the other, which might not be what you want.
This is where Promise.all comes in. This function takes an array of pending promises and resolved only when all of them are resolved. So you could build an array with pending promises, one for each document to fetch, and then await the Promise.all function.
/* ... */

async function fetchDocuments(documentToFetch) {
  const validToken = await validateToken()

  const pendingPromises = []
  for(let i = 0; i < documentToFetch; i ++) {
    pendingPromises.push(fetchDocument(validToken));
  }

  await Promise.all(pendingPromises)
}

Now, all the document fetch requests will be run in parallel, and the fetchDocuments function will only resolve once all of the documents are fetched.

Thank you for your suggested approach, but I don't think it would work for my scenario. It would limit the way I fetch my data, and as you said, I'd have to fetch them all using one fetchDocuments function. This way it would be impossible to make requests one-after-another, such as when a user clicks several submit buttons before the first request is able to complete refreshing the access token.
